# SharePoint as DMS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I don't need to use any features like notification, workflow, I only plan to store about 16 Tera of documents with a good performance.

Is SharePoint suitable for this scenario? If No , What's the alternative solutions?

Comment: How do you expect to get a comparison between one of a series of mature products and a protocol?  It sound to me like you want us to tell you that just retrieving doucments via SFTP will be cheaper/faster than using SharePoint. And it might or might not depending on what you need.

Comment: Thanks @perjakobsen for your reply,  i have already SharePoint farm but I need to switch to SFTP to avoid storage content database  issue because data will be up to 16 Tera. if I continue with SharePoint what's the issues? What is the alternative solutions ?

Comment: The only requirement is good performance? No versioning no permission control No mobile device? A local SAN is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

16 tera byte is huge amount of data which required proper planning. You cant put the 16 tera byte in single site collection or single content databse.while planning you should keep following limitation.

- List view threshold( if you have more than 10K(sp 2016) document in a view then it will be an issue)
- a content Database grow upto 4 Terabyte but exceeding beyond 4TB required a lot work.
- Backup and recovery will be hell
- Performance of SharePoint

Check this white paper for more understanding for planning the large content DB palnning. http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/3/E/03E118BC-B686-440B-8C54-E46CC7043D53/managing-multi-terabyte-databases-SharePoint-2010.pdf

As you just need to store the documents and dont want to use the other features. I would recommend dont use sharepoint and look for alternate i.e [Box](https://www.box.com/) or Drop box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some analysis on the data on hand.

Is it possible to break it down into manageable chunks for example say by department etc.

Then you can create multiple site collections each with its own database.